# Deploying a netbeans 6.9 java web application on websphere application server 6.1 with Java EE 5 specification

Tags: java, deployment, netbeans, websphere

I have developed a **Java web application in netbeans 6.9 with Java EE 5 specifications**.The .war file of the project in "dist" folder is converted to .ear file. I tried to deploy either .war file or **.ear file on websphere application server 6.1 but i am getting an exception that either .ear file may be corrupted or incomplete or DeploymentDescriptionException**. Help me in this matter.

And does **netbeans 6.9 have any plugin for WebSphere Application Server 6.1 0r 7**, as netbeans 6.9 doesn't show websphere application server in the servers list.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been told in forums, NetBeans does not support officially Websphere, unfortunatelly.